# Type bit does not match with the integer literal while converting integer into bit_vector

Tags: vhdl, conversion

In VHDL, is there any way to convert an `integer` into `bit_vector` of length of 14?

Currently, I am first converting the `integer` into `std_logic_vector` and then into `bit_vector`.

```vhdl
for i in 0 to 5 loop
    x_std(i) <= conv_std_logic_vector(x_int(i),14);
    x_bit(i) <= to_bitvector(x_std(i),14);   --here comes error
end loop;
```

In behavioral check syntax, following error comes while converting `std_logic` into `bit`:

```
Type bit does not match with the integer literal
```

I am using following libraries, `ieee.std_logic_1164`, `std_logic_arith` and `std_logic_unsigned`.

How can I do this conversion without an error?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/vhdl-converting-from-an-integer-type-to-a-std-logic-vector

Visit this link !

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir. But I want integer to bit_vector conversion not std logic vector conversion.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question: the `to_bitvector()` function from `std_logic_1164` only takes one input, a signal of type `std_ulogic_vector` or `std_logic_vector`. If you search for the function name you find documentation like [this](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/std_logic/1164/to_bitvector.html) which gives the interface

```vhdl
function to_bitvector ( s : std_ulogic_vector ) return bit_vector;
```

So change your code to this and it should work (though I haven't tested):

```
for i in 0 to 5 loop
    x_std(i) <= conv_std_logic_vector(x_int(i),14);
    x_bit(i) <= to_bitvector(x_std(i));  --should compile
end loop;
```

---

As to why the functions take different inputs, the `conv_std_logic_vector` function requires a length parameter as the `integer` type has no specific length. The length parameter tells the synthesiser how wide a `std_logic_vector` is created by the function. VHDL is strongly typed and the length of the signal returned from the function is then checked against the left hand sign on the assignment (`x_std(i)`) to ensure they match.

Conversely, the `to_bitvector` function simply goes through each element of the array in turn performing a mapping from `std_logic` to `bit` and the returned array width is therefore defined by the width of the input array.

It's also worth looking into using [VHDL attributes](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/attribute.html) as the length input to conversion functions. This code won't break if you decide to change the width of `x_std()` and `x_bit()` later:

```
x_std(i) <= conv_std_logic_vector(x_int(i),x_std(i)'LENGTH);
```

Comment: Also many people have moved away from using the `std_logic_arith` package and its conversion functions in favour of `ieee.numeric_std`. I've found [this](http://www.synthworks.com/papers/vhdl_math_tricks_mapld_2003.pdf) presentation very helpful