# Problem with Octal to Binary in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, binary

it,s me... Again. I tried almost everything but i can't make it work properly. This is my code:

```
library ieee;
-- Import all the declarations in a package
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity Octal is
port
(
--Puertos de entrada
    B8  : in  integer range 0 to 17;

-- Puertos de Salida
    Binario : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end Octal;
--Empezamos con la arquitectura
architecture comportamiento of Octal is
begin
process(B8)
        begin
            if B8 = 0 then
                Binario <= "0000";
            elsif B8 = 1 then
                Binario <= "0001";
            elsif B8 = 2 then
                Binario <= "0010";
            elsif B8 = 3 then
                Binario <= "0011";
            elsif B8 = 4 then
                Binario <= "0100";
            elsif B8 = 5 then
                Binario <= "0101";
            elsif B8 = 6 then
                Binario <= "0110";
            elsif B8 = 7 then
                Binario <= "0111";
            elsif B8 = 10 then
                Binario <= "1000";
            elsif B8 = 11 then
                Binario <= "1001";
            elsif B8 = 12 then
                Binario <= "1010";
            elsif B8 = 13 then
                Binario <= "1011";
            elsif B8 = 14 then
                Binario <= "1100";
            elsif B8 = 15 then
                Binario <= "1101";
            elsif B8 = 16 then
                Binario <= "1110";
            elsif B8 = 17 then
                Binario <= "1111";  
            end if;
    end process;    

end comportamiento;
```

I don't know why, but it's something wrong on the waveform. This is an octal to binary VHDL code. Thank you.

EDIT:
I change the value from B8 to "range 0 to 17" but it mismatched in the waveform:
[image: Waveform image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want the `if B8 = XX` literals to be octal, not decimal. Try using the octal literal notation: `if B8 = 8#XX#`.

Your input range is max 16:

```
B8  : in  integer range 0 to 16;
```

But you're comparing against values up to 17:

```
elsif B8 = 17 then
```

Try increasing your input range to `0 to 17` or `0 to 8#17#` depending on whether you want that to be octal or decimal.

Also take a look at this answer about converting integer to std_logic_vector. Octal is just a notation, if you're not actually changing the underlying signal's value you can do this:
[VHDL: Converting from an INTEGER type to a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/15033/242952)